# CRM 2013 Reporting Issues

Tags: express, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to generate a report, and I have a custom column. Sometimes the column works, and other times it does not.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqCyK.jpg

As you can see, the column works sometimes and does not other times. Why is this?

The code for the column is:

```
=iif(Fields!ask_response.Value>Fields!ask_totalduration.Value, "Time Met", "Time not Met")
```

It does not work, but I am unable to work out why it does not.

Comment: Looks like some kind of grouping going on in your report. Try wrapping the fields in a sum so they add up the values in the group.

Comment: Which coloum should i sum sorry?

Comment: Both of them
=iif(SUM(Fields!ask_response.Value)>SUM(Fields!ask_totalduration.Value), "Time Met", "Time not Met")

Comment: Hi @KevinRoss Thanks for the help, I am now having the issue where the report shows #error

Comment: Could be if the output of the sum is not a number i.e. adding up null values. Best to check your data source and coalesce them out

Comment: I have a Cdbl and a Cdec